# Invalid object name 'product_Design'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, database-schema

I am getting this error while saving my data into the table. I have already created a 'product_Design' table in my database. I am using Sql Server 2008. Everything is working fine on local host but not on the server. I also tried to insert data in different tables and its working but I am just not able to insert data in this(product_Design) table ? I really need help regarding this thing.

here is my sql query

```
insert into z3ctjholo.dbo.product_Design values(@prodID, @productName, @designName, @designPath, @finalDesign, @front, @cont, @divHeight, GETDATE(), 0, 1)
```

I also tried this query

```
insert into product_Design values(@prodID, @productName, @designName, @designPath, @finalDesign, @front, @cont, @divHeight, GETDATE(), 0, 1)
```

Both the queries are generating error. Please help me out.

Thanks..

Comment: Are you sure you created the table in the correct database ? What happens when you do `SELECT * FROM dbo.product_Design`

Comment: What's the result of this query: `select * from z3ctjholo.sys.objects where name = 'product_Design'`?

Comment: @M.Ali its showing an error Invalid object product_Design. If i execute query in sql server directly then its working but when i try to execute it from my asp.net application its giving an error.

Comment: @dean showing an error Invalid object name product_Design

Comment: You're targeting either a wrong server (test, dev vs prod) or the wrong database.

Comment: my other tables are working fine, if i would have been targeting a wrong server then i would have got error while inserting the data in other tables. @dean

Comment: Ok then, you've create the table on the wrong server/database. In any case, there is no product_design table in z3ctjholo database in dbo schema. Or the schema was wrong?

Comment: but i can access my table through sql server. It is present there. I can modify, insert, select data from it. But when i try to access it from my asp.net application it is showing an error.

Comment: Well then, run the profiler and see what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally i found what is the problem. if you ever face such kind of problem then execute this command in sql server and see whether your table is connected to any schema apart from dbo. Use this statement to check whether the table is connected to any other schema.

```
use yourDatabaseName
```

Then

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

after that if you find that your table is connected with other schema apart from dbo then use your any statement like this

```
select * from schemaName.tableName
```

(eg. my schema name is z3ctjholo and my table name is product_Design)

so my statement would be like this

```
select * from z3ctjholo.product_Design
```

what i was doing wrong, i was using two schema names (z3ctjholo.dbo.product_Design).

I hope it will help someone..

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons, I can find so far.
1. Either the connection settings in web.config is incorrect.
2. your database is case sensitive collation and so check the name with case. May be you have created the table with name Product_Design and trying to insert in product_Design, in this case also, the command may not work.

Please check both the points.